# Capture entire defanged url or normal url with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to capture an entire defanged or regular url using regex. This is the regex pattern I have been using so far (?:[a-zA-Z]+://)?[\w]+?(?:[.]|.)[\w]+?(?:[.]|.)[\w]+

This has been effective and capturing these type of urls:

```
http://www.google.com
hxxp://www[.]google[.]com
hxxp://www.google[.]com
foob://www[.]google.com
```

I want to capture the entire url. If I have a url that looks like this:

```
hxxp://midtjyskbogfoering_dk/sendincsec/support/trust/En_en/02-2019/
```

What should I add to capture the entire url content. I've experimented with adding (?:/\w) at the end of my last regex expression making this the entire pattern (?:[a-zA-Z]+://)?[\w]+?(?:[.]|.)[\w]+?(?:[.]|.)[\w]+(?:/\w) but this doesnt give me what I'm looking for. I'm just started learning regex yesterday so any insight with a good explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: try adding `(?:\/\w+)*` at the end

Comment: Thats pretty close it gives me everything up until -2019/. Im still missing that part of the pattern

Comment: change the regex to include `-` like `(?:\/[\w-]+)*`

Comment: yep that did it I am now matching the full pattern (?:[a-zA-Z]+://)?[\w]+?(?:[.]|.)[\w]+?(?:[.]|.)[\w]+(?:\/[\w-]+)* is the full pattern thank you